# Regex - require a specific digit to be contained in \d+?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the python code:

```
import re

re.findall('[0-9]+', 'XYZ 102 1030')
```

which returns:

```
['102', '1030']
```

Can one write a regex that requires at least one occurance of the digit `3`, i.e. I am interested in `'[0-9]+'` where there is at least one `3`? So the result of interest would be:

```
['1030']
```

More generally, how about at least `n` `3`'s?

And even more generally, how about at least `n` `3`'s and at least `k` `4`'s, etc?

Comment: Do you only want to match tokens that are all digits? For example, `foo3bar` contains a 3; do you want to match it?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? You haven't commented on any of them...

Answer (score 2):

At least one `3` in the string could be

```
\d*3\d*
```

https://regex101.com/r/yEbatk/4

If you are looking for (at least) 2 times the number `3` inside, you could use:

```
\d*3\d*3\d*
```

https://regex101.com/r/yEbatk/5

If you want it to be (at least) `n` times you could use the [`{min,max}` repeat option](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
\d*(3\d*){n}
```

https://regex101.com/r/yEbatk/7

Comment: @aragaer, you are right. I just upvoted joanolo's answer for that :) I can update the answer...

Comment: @aragaer: you can also save your `\d*` at the end of your last example; it's already within the parens.

Comment: @joanolo I think the answer is better now

Answer (score 2):

Just try the regexp `'\d*3\d*'`, which means "0 or more digits, followed by a 3, followed by 0 or more digits".

You can [check it here](https://regex101.com/r/0yTnPB/1)

If you want "at least 'n' 3", use `'\d*(3\d*){n}'`.

Comment: Got my vote for not using the group (`[3]`) i used in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For *n* occurrences of `x`, *m* occurrences of `y`, and so on, build forth on this general expression:

```
(?=(?:\d*x){n})(?=(?:\d*y){m})\b\d+\b
```

where the lookahead part `(?=(?:\d*x){n})` is repeated for each desired `n` and `x`.

I chose to make the lookahead groups non-capturing by surrounding them with `(?:..)`, although it makes it a bit less readable.

The counting part itself is just `(\d*x){n}`, and it needs a lookahead because with more than one set of numbers to look for, the digits may appear in any order.

The final `\b\d+\b` ensures you capture just digits, surrounded by 'not-word' characters, so it will skip any sequence containing letters but *will* work on something like `abc-123-456`.

Example: 2 3's and 2 4's, in `XYZ 1023344a 1403403`

```
(?=(?:\d*3){2})(?=(?:\d*4){2})\b\d+\b
```

will match `1403403` but not `1023344a`.

See
https://regex101.com/r/QgYptp/3

Answer (score 1):

Although you *can* use a regex for this, regexes get messy and hard to read when you're searching for more than a couple of different digits. Instead, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurrences of each character in a string:

```
from collections import Counter

# Must contain at least two 3s, three 4s, and one 7
mins = { '3': 2, '4': 3, '7': 1 }

input = '3444 33447 334447 foo334447 473443 2317349414'
tokens = input.split()

for token in tokens:
    # Skip tokens that aren't numbers
    if not token.isdigit():
        continue

    counter = Counter(token)

    for digit, min_count in mins.items():
        if counter[digit] < min_count:
            break
    else:
        print(token)
```

Output:

```
334447
473443
2317349414
```